# How to bind this to a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My previous question was a duplicate, I read the answer from the [post it duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) but no luck.

I've added in a bind as suggested in the answers in the SO post. But I am still getting undefined.

I have a series of promises, before each execution, I check whether the user has cancelled the promise chain.

My issue is, I cannot access 'this' inside the call back methods, a crude example is below, I cannot access the p.test variable inside getMoreData()

```js
p.test = 'hello!';

p.init = function(){ 
    var self = this;

    this.getData() 
        .then(function(data) {
            return self.shouldContinue(getMoreData,data).bind(self);
        });
}

p.shouldContinue = function(cb, data) {
    // ...
    this.currentRequest = cb.call(this,data);
};

p.getData = function(){
    // return ajax call
};

p.getMoreData = function(){
    console.log(this.test); // undefined
    // return ajax call
};
```

Comment: I've amended the question with new code. The suggestion did not work.

Comment: Because you didn't define `self` at `return self.shouldContinue(getMoreData,data).bind(self);`

Comment: This is exactly my code, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, you did't do something like `var self = this;` before any thing, so `self` is `undefined`.

Comment: Self is defined. So this is not the issue.

Comment: Hang on; I think there are some important parts to this suggested by your code comments that may not have been noticed. An AJAX call can register a callback in two ways; one, by passing one into the ajax function, or two, by returning something to the effect of a "Promise object" that you can return through the call chain, and call `prom.then(function() {})` on. But I'm not certain you're doing either. You have no arguments to `getMoreData`, and you're never calling `.then` - you're treating the result of `getMoreData` like it's a function. Adding a bit more code would help explain the intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
return self.shouldContinue(getMoreData,data).bind(self);
```

It looks like you're accidentally *calling* shouldContinue, and trying to bind its result, rather than binding the function without calling it. This should get you what you need.

```
return self.shouldContinue.bind(self, self.getMoreData, data);
```

Remember that `getMoreData` is a function that's not defined under variable scope, so it needs to be accessed with a `.`

EDIT: Also noticed `shouldContinue` has a similar issue, but I'm confused by the intent of some parts of your code so I've added a comment to ask for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but self.shouldContinue.bind(self, self.getMoreData, data); now no longer calls the getMoreData fnc

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
You need to bind `this` into the cb

```
p.test = 'hello!';

p.init = function(){
var self = this;
this.getData() 
    .then(function(data) {
        return self.shouldContinue(getMoreData,data).bind(self);
    })
}

p.shouldContinue = function(cb, data){
   ...
  this.currentRequest = cb(this,data).bind(this);
};

p.getData = function(){
    //return ajax call
};

p.getMoreData = function(){
    console.log(this.test); //undefined
    //return ajax call
};
```

Comment: This gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
 p.init = function(){ 
      var self = this;

      this.getData() 
          .then(function(data) {
              return self.shouldContinue.bind(self, self.getMoreData, data)();
          });
  }
```

1. bind `self.shouldContinue` to `self` and give it appropriate param.
2. `.bind`  returns a `Function`, so, you need to call it.So the `self.shouldContinue` will continues to call `self.getMoreData`, otherwise it left there waiting to be called.